# I want to pass different objects to my method, how to solve ArrayList is a raw type... warning

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following method and I wish to pass different objects (POJOs) to it. How should I handle initializing `ArrayList outObjects` correctly? Code below results in warning in for this line:

```
ArrayList outObjects = new ArrayList<>();
```

*"ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList should be parameterized"*

I can't seem to find a solution how to initialize `outObjects` and still keep my code funcional. Do I have some fundamental design flaw in it?

To clarify:
I want the code to be able to handle different kind of objects, which is why I can't use initialization eg. `ArrayList<Company>`, I want to keep it generic so it can handle `Customer`, `Reservation` etc. as well. These objects are given to the method with `Object inObject`.

```
public List<Object> executeSelect(String query, Object inObject) {
    ArrayList outObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        PreparedStatement ps = connectionGlobal.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        ArrayList<String> namesOfColumns = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            namesOfColumns.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1));
        }

        Object result = inObject.getClass();

        if (result.equals(Company.class)) {
            outObjects = new ArrayList<Company>();
        }

        while (rs.next()) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
                String value = rs.getString(i + 1);
                if (rs.wasNull()) {
                    map.put(namesOfColumns.get(i), "{NULL}");
                } else {
                    map.put(namesOfColumns.get(i), value.trim());
                }

            }

            Company company = mapper.convertValue(map, Company.class);
            outObjects.add(company);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return outObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just storing objects of type Company in the outObjects array just make it:

```
ArrayList<Company> outObjects = new ArrayList<>();
```

or if you need to store other objects you could make it:

```
ArrayList<Object> outObjects = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. If i try to initialize it as ArrayList object i get problems here  `if (result.equals(Company.class)) {
    outObjects = new ArrayList<Company>();
   }` Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<Company> to ArrayList<Object> any tips on resolving that?

Comment: If you need to keep objects of different types then just keep 'outObjects' as ArrayList<Object> and don't change it with the line 'outObjects = new ArrayList<Company>();', just remove that line.

Comment: Ah brilliant, i don't know why I added that! It solved the case. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Since all classes extend Object in Java, and the expected classes dont share another subclass, you can initialize it like this.

```
ArrayList<Object> outObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: Im sorry the question was unclear, i typed in the title i wish to pass different objects. Example type Company, Reservation, Customer. Editing this to the question.